# Overloading function with char and uint8_t types

Tags: c++, char, overloading, uint8t

To implement a basic interface for an LCD I need to write the function `print` for all basic types. I need to write

```
void print(char c);
```

and also

```
void print(uint8_t c);
```

The first function tells: "I want to write the character `c`", and the second tells "I want to write the number `c`". These 2 functions have different meanings, so I need both of them.

The problem is that `uint8_t` is a typedef of `char`. If I call

```
print(20u);
```

the compiler gives an error because it doesn't know which version of `print` to choose.

My question is: How to solve this problem?

My solutions:

1. Define 2 differents functions:

```
void print(char c);
void print_number(uint8_t x);
void print(uint16_t x);
...
```

The problem with this solution is that you have to remember that when you want to print an `uint8_t` you have to call `print_number`. This complicate all the generic code that I need to write. I don't think is 'the solution'.

2. Write my proper class `uint8_t` and instead of using the standard `uint8_t` use my own version.
   This solution has different problems:

   - I don't think is a good idea to have an alternative to the standard type `uint8_t`.
   - If I write my own version of `uint8_t`, for instance, `Uint8_t` for consistency I have to write all the other types also (`Uint16_t`, `Uint32_t`, ...) and I don't like that too.
3. ??? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `The problem is that uint8_t is a typedef of char` it's not. It's an alias of `unsigned char`

Comment: Does it help to distinguish `signed` and `unsigned char` explicitly? IIRC it's implementation defined how that's handled. Anyway I believe it's better design, to be explicit via function names, rather than generic parameter types for that case.

Comment: Turn your `print` into a template function, then use `if constexpr` to detect the type of `T` and choose the appropriate print method.

Comment: `the compiler gives an error because it doesn't know which version of print to choose.` do you know which version to use? Cant you guide the compiler at call time?

Comment: `20u` is considered to be a `unsigned int` though and neither an `uint8_t` nor a `char`.

Comment: @fabian you are right. Thats the problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this might not be the solution you're looking for, but if you type cast while passing the parameter, it works.
`print((char) 20u)` will call the `print(char c)`
and
`print((uint8_t) 20u)` will call the `print(uint8_t c)`

Comment: Advising c-like casts is a little... borderline [ES,4.9](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es49-if-you-must-use-a-cast-use-a-named-cast). There are also `char` literals and even *user-defined literals*.

Comment: The underlying issue in the question is that `char` and `uint8_t` are **the same type**.  Casting to `char` doesn't change that. If you tested it and it worked, it's because your compiler makes them different types.